# When is my struct too large?

Tags: swift, class, struct, heap-memory, stack-memory

We're encouraged to use `struct` over `class` in Swift.

This is because

1. The compiler can do a lot of optimizations
2. Instances are created on the stack which is a lot more performant than `malloc`/`free` calls

The downside to `struct` variables is that they are copied each time when returning from or assigned to a function. Obviously, this can become a bottleneck too.

E.g. imagine a 4x4 matrix. 16 Float values would have to be copied on every assign/return which would be 1'024 bits on a 64 bit system.

One way you can avoid this is using `inout` when passing variables to functions, which is basically Swifts way of creating a pointer. But then we're also discouraged from using `inout`.

So to my question:
How should I handle large, immutable data structures in Swift?
Do I have to worry creating a large `struct` with many members?
If yes, when am I crossing the line?

Comment: "We're encouraged" Who came up with that policy? Somebody that wants to prevent good code?

Comment: @idmean It makes much sense using structs. Remember, this advice mainly comes from the Swift team, surely they know, having written the optimizer themselves.

Comment: Probably in some cases these fractions of seconds are relevant, but I generally think that well structured code helps preventing bugs, which also leads to better and faster code. But just my opinion.

Comment: Structs promote immutability, which helps prevent bugs in many many cases. The difference is not fractions of seconds but it can be quite drastic.

Comment: Structs also remove the need for dynamic dispatch which is one most important speed improvements (unless you need polymorphism).

Comment: Okay, we could discuss that for ages. To your question: Of course very big structs are bad as they are, as you said, allocated on the stack.

Comment: Pure Swift classes don't use dynamic dispatch, and access modifiers (according immutability).

Comment: @idmean Yes that's true, I'll give you that one. "Of course very big structs are bad" Then, how big is "very big"?

Comment: It's too big in the moment it becomes a bottleneck. If you have a "huge" struct that will only copy once a minute in a background thread and no one will notice, then it's not too big.

Comment: @NiñoScript Well of course, but when does it become a bottleneck, meaning, when does allocating on the heap become faster than creating it on the stack and e.g. passing it to a function.

Comment: @NSAddict I think that's the kind of thing you need to test. You'll know it's a bottleneck when your app needs to be faster, you open your profiler (Instruments) and it clearly says the bottleneck is the copy. Don't give up the safety of your large struct until it hurts, or you'll be just another victim of premature optimization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This accepted answer is not entirely answering the question you had: Swift always copies structs. The trick that Array/Dictionary/String/etc do is that they are just wrappers around classes (which contain the actual stored properties). That way sizeof(Array) is just the size of the pointer to that class (`MemoryLayout<Array<String>>.stride == MemoryLayout<UnsafeRawPointer>.stride`)

If you have a really big struct, you might want to consider wrapping its stored properties in a class for efficient passing around as arguments, and checking `isUniquelyReferenced` before mutating to give COW semantics.

Structs have other efficiency benefits: they don't need reference-counting and can be decomposed by the optimiser.

> In Swift, values keep a unique copy of their data. There are several
>   advantages to using value-types, like ensuring that values have
>   independent state. When we copy values (the effect of assignment,
>   initialization, and argument passing) the program will create a new
>   copy of the value. For some large values these copies could be time
>   consuming and hurt the performance of the program.

https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OptimizationTips.rst#the-cost-of-large-swift-values

Also the section on container types:

> Keep in mind that there is a trade-off between using large value types
>   and using reference types. In certain cases, the overhead of copying
>   and moving around large value types will outweigh the cost of removing
>   the bridging and retain/release overhead.

Comment: You're right. But wouldn't the overhead from reference counting and heap-allocation destroy the performance benefits from using structs? The only benefit then would be the COW semantics.

Comment: Well, it depends how you think of it. Apple's experience with Foundation taught them that String, Array, etc should all be values. The fact that they aren't value-types in Objective-C means that you often need to defensively copy them to ensure you have a unique reference to the underlying storage. COW is a big performance win because it replaces those defensive copies with ones that known to be required (e.g, because two Array references point to the same backing, and one wants to mutate).

Comment: Also, resizable elements will always need heap allocation. Otherwise, the size of any stack frame which uses an Array or String would depend on its length.

I remember that in the first Swift beta, "let"-annotated Arrays were still mutable, as long as you didn't change their length. Maybe they were trying to go for something like that. People didn't like that system, protested and we got COW instead.

Comment: That makes sense. Although we rarely had to defensively copy arrays and the like because they were immutable by default. I guess the biggest plus point is that we have one type for both mutable and immutable arrays.

Comment: It's also worth noting that COW has come to Obj-C in iOS 11, so those defensive copies shouldn't be nearly as expensive. Swift will still be probably faster due to compile-time generics, static dispatching and aggressive inlining. Struct vs. class shouldn't have a massive impact: structs have no subtypes or virtual members, but the Swift compiler can devirtualize non-open classes inside the same module anyway. Just easier semantics.

Comment: Agreed. Final classes should have very similar performance apart from the overhead from heap allocation.

Answer (score 3):

From the very bottom of [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html) page from the Swift Reference:

> NOTE
>
> The description above refers to the “copying” of strings, arrays, and dictionaries. The behavior you see in your code will always be as if a copy took place. However, Swift only performs an actual copy behind the scenes when it is absolutely necessary to do so. Swift manages all value copying to ensure optimal performance, and you should not avoid assignment to try to preempt this optimization.

I hope this answers your question, also if you want to be sure that an array doesn't get copied, you can always declare the parameter as `inout`, and pass it with `&array` into the function.

Also classes add a lot of overhead and should only be used if you really must have a reference to the same object.

Examples for structs:

- Timezone
- Latitude/Longitude
- Size/Weight

Examples for classes:

- Person
- A View

Comment: That's awesome! I actually read that back when Swift came out and I completely forgot about it.