# swift MemoryLayout for class and struct

Tags: swift, memory-layout

I am investigating `MemoryLayout` and I came across this:

```
struct A {
    var name:String
}
```

```
class B {
    var name:String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

```
let a = A(name: "a")
let sizeA = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: a)
print("struct size: " + "\(sizeA)")    // 16
   
let b = B(name: "B")
let sizeB = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: b)
print("class size: " + "\(sizeB)").   // 8
```

Can you please explain to me why the size is different?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When using `size(ofValue:)` for a `class`, the returned value is the size of the pointer of that class. However, when dealing with a struct it returns the size of that instance hence the diffrence.

More info here: [When is my struct too large?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560201/when-is-my-struct-too-large)